# SQL Server return wrong result when I use LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, sql-like

I created a new DB `"TEST"`, add a new table `"tblTest"` and 1 column `"Name"` in it.

Insert some records: Minh, Tinh, Justin

```
create database TEST
go
use test
go
create table tblTest (Name varchar(50))
go
insert tblTest values ('Minh')
insert tblTest values ('Tinh')
insert tblTest values ('Justin')
```

Then I run this query

```
Select * from tblTest where Name like '%in%'
```

The result is: Justin. (Minh and Tinh are not display)

Anyone can tell me how to fix this?

Comment: That should work. What does "Select * from tblTest" return?

Comment: Also from your results it looks like the 2nd % is not there.

Comment: Can you show us the create and insert statements?

Comment: I suspect foreign characters.

Comment: Data types? Can we assume it is a nvarchar and "Tinh" and "Minh" are not using "IN" (as english) but something foreign with accent that just happens to look similar, but is not similar?

Comment: Have a look at this buddy http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18330

Comment: can you confirm if the data type of Name is something like char(6)?

Comment: @Deepshikha it's varchar(50)

Comment: @TomTom it's varchar(50)

Comment: @Jens I've already added it on top

Comment: @Bobby "select * from tblTest" works fine. And yes, it looks like 2nd % is not working

Comment: @Kelvin after the insert Statements you must add a ';'

Comment: @Kevein have you made a commit after insert the data?

Comment: Perhaps it's a collation issue?

Answer (score 0):

See if this query is working and providing the necessary output.

```
with tblTest as
(
   Select 'Minh' name from dual union
   Select 'Tinh' name from dual union
   Select 'Justin' name from dual 
)
Select * from tblTest where Name like '%in%'
```

Else, delete all records from tblTest using:

```
DELETE from tblTest;
```

Then, insert records using:

```
INSERT INTO TBLTEST (NAME) VALUES ('Minh');
INSERT INTO TBLTEST (NAME) VALUES ('Tinh');
INSERT INTO TBLTEST (NAME) VALUES ('Justin');
```

Now try executing your `SELECT` query again.
As @podiluska pointed out, there could be some foreign junk characters.

Comment: I have re-installed Windows again, it totally not work, the result is the same.
I have 3 laptops, 2 of them give the wrong result (same DB, same query)

Comment: @Kelvin It's not windows, it's not SQL Server. It's your data.

Comment: According to the syntax used ("Dual" table) you're working with Oracle; the question is about MS SQL (possible) misbehaviour. Oracle does its work with LIKE alright.

Comment: @podiluska I use the same database in 3 laptops, 2 of them gave the wrong result, the 3rd one gave right.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example, its give me your result as you want. First % is used for preceed and Last % used for succeeded.

```
declare @t table (name varchar(50))
insert into @t values('Minh'),('Tinh'),('Justin')

Select * from @t where Name like '%in%'
```

Result will be

```
name
Minh
Tinh
Justin
```

Comment: are you try my example. what comes in output of this at your end?

Comment: Yes, I did. But the output was "Justin" again.